# What's the worst space complexity of a loop which create an arrayat each iteration

Tags: c, algorithm, space-complexity

I am struggling to find a proper definition of worst space complexity whether it is the sum of the total amount of the algorithm used or if it is only the space consumed by the algorithm at a critical time, the worst one.

As an example:

```
void myFunc(n) {
  for(int j = 0; j < n ; ++j) {
     int* myTab = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
     for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        myTab[i] = 1;
     }
      free(myTab);
   }
}
```

For the first definition it is roughly `O(N²)` and for the second one `O(N)`.

Comment: The same space can be reused. You need to know the inner workings of `malloc()` (and the load on the system, and the day of the week, ...) to be sure ... but I say you can safely assume `O(n)` space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be `O(n)`. You are explicitly freeing up the memory after the assignment is done. I agree the inner workings of the `malloc` would be useful but assuming a normal implementation which doesn't use memory enough to change the space complexity ( For tracking `O(n)` memory allocation it keeps `O(n^2)` amounts of metadata - just a weird example).

An interesting point, to clear up your idea. If you comment out this `free(..)` line, then the space complexity would be `O(n^2)`.  This is what is known as memory leakage.